# Associative bilinear form that is unital

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

I encountered a vector space with an associative bilinear map that is also unital... And I feel like this implies that this vector space is actually an algebra over the underlying field. Am I right?

Associative is the condition $u(u(x,y),z)=u(x,u(y,z))$ and unital is the condition that there exists $e\in V$ the underlying vector space $V$ such that $u(x,e)=u(e,x)=x$ for all $x\in V$.

Thank you. Have a nice day!

Comment: What does it mean for a bilinear form to be "associative" and "unital"?

Comment: I will edit in a moment! Thanks for asking for clarifying!

Comment: help if you give a specific source, especially a published book

Comment: that is not what usually called a bilinear *form* but rather a bilinear *map* but yes, that is just an associative, unital algebra

Comment: @WillJagy No,, it is not from a published book...

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Oh! I'm sorry,,, it should be bilinear map! not form.;;; sorry for the confusion there... I would edit it just for the record. And thank you Sebastian! Hope you have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a definition of an **algebra** (which makes it apparent how to define a **coalgebra**).

**Def 1**: Let $K$ be a field. An (associative unital) $K$-algebra is a triple of data $(A, \mu, \eta)$ such that $A$ is a $K$-vector space, $\mu: A\times A\to A$ is a bilinear map called *multiplication map*, and $\eta: K\to A$ a linear map called *unit*. Such that

- Associativity: For all $x,y,z\in A$, one has $\mu(\mu(x,y), z)=\mu(x, \mu(y,z))$.
- Unital: For all $x\in A$ and $\alpha\in K$, $\mu(\eta(\alpha),x)=\alpha x=\mu(x, \eta(\alpha))$.

with this definition the element $e\in A$ that you mentioned is $e=\eta(1)$. Sometimes, using universal property of tensor product people instead define $\mu: A\otimes A\to A$ (linear) instead. The latter comes in handy actually.

**Def 2**: Let $K$ be a field, $A$ a ring equipped with a homomorphism $f: K\to A$. Then $A$ is called a $K$-algebra.

To see the equivalence of these definitions, say we start from def 2: Define $\eta$ as the underlying $K$-linear map of $f$. Also since $A$ is a ring, it already comes equipped with a associative bilinear map $\mu: A\times A\to A$. Moreover $A$ is obviously a $K$-vector space with scalar product $\alpha x=\mu(f(\alpha),x)=\mu(x, f(\alpha))=x\alpha$. So done.

Conversely, say we start with def 1: Then together $(A,\mu)$ is a ring. Now consider the map $\eta: K\to A$. Note that if $\alpha, \beta\in K$, then
$$
\eta(\alpha\beta)=\alpha \eta(\beta)=\mu(\eta(\alpha), \eta(\beta))
$$
Hence $\eta$ is actually a ring homomorphism, not just a $K$-linear map.